# c++ adding a numbers in a coloumn from a input file

Tags: c++

Probably a very easy question but i am missing the whole loop concept here.

I have a resource file with data something like this called `input.txt`. First is the id column with string type but rest column are double.

```
1111    10 20 30 
2222    11 22 33
3333    22 23 24
4444    33 33 34
```

Now, I have to write a c++ program where i have to cout average of 1st, 2nd and 3rd column.
I did wrote the program and score full point in a test but I know we can use loop here and do it easy way. Help. Here is my working program.

```
double q1, q2, q3, ave1, ave2, ave3;
double sum = 0; 
double sum2 =0;
double sum3 =0;
while(fin >> id ){

    fin >> q1 >> q2 >> q3;
    sum = sum+ q1; 
    q1++;
     ave1 = sum /4;

    sum2 = sum2 + q2;
    q2++;
     ave2 = sum2/4;

    sum3 = sum3 + q3;
    q3++;
     ave3 = sum2/4;
}
cout << "The average of q1 " << ave1<< endl;
cout << "The average of q2 " << ave2<< endl;
cout << "The average of q3 " << ave3<< endl;

fin.close();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post your fully working code, including the input and output, at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: What is the question ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you read the Id in id var and q1,q2,q3 are double values means,

```
int count =0;
while(fin >> id){
count ++;
fin >> q1 >> q2 >>q3 ; 
sum += q1;
sum2 += q2; 
sum3 += q3;
}
cout << "Average q1 " << sum/count; //if you want double result use count as double
cout << "Average q2" << sum2/count;
cout << "Average q2" << sum3/count;
```

Let us know for more info..

For every loop it is same as simple

```
int count =0;
    while(fin >> id){
    count ++;
    fin >> q1 >> q2 >>q3 ; 
    sum += q1;
    sum2 += q2; 
    sum3 += q3;

    cout << "Average q1 " << sum/count; //if you want double result use count as double
    cout << "Average q2" << sum2/count;
    cout << "Average q2" << sum3/count;
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: this works, but i was looking for the solution using the loop. Thanks

Comment: @user3071451 : if you want the average for every line , then end the while loop after the last cout .. 
That means we are calculating the average for every lines of input .

Answer (score 0):

For educational value, will mention that you can use arrays and loops to help your program scale to larger numbers of columns without having to write more code...

```
const int num_columns = 3;
size_t lines = 0;
double sum[num_columns] = { 0 };
while(fin >> id ){
{
    ++lines;
    for (int col = 0; col < num_columns; ++col)
    {
        int num;
        assert(fin >> num);
        sum[col] += num;
    }
}

double ave[num_columns];
for (int col = 0; col < num_columns; ++col)
    ave[col] = sum[col] / lines;
for (int col = 0; col < num_columns; ++col)
    std::cout << "The average of q" << col + 1 << " is " << ave[col] << '\n';
// ABOVE, you could have one loop print sum[col]/lines directly, without ave[]
```